# Close Internet Explorer Programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, vbscript, browser

Is there any way IE can be closed programmatically?

I am trying to build a simple login system for the school I am working at in which a pupil would sign in using a HTML form and when they click the submit button the window will close automatically.

I have tried this using JavaScript (close() seems to be redundant now), VBScript (.Quit) and trying to run a .cmd file to close it externally (Windows Script Host). None of these have worked.

I am not doing this maliciously and I have absolutely no bad intentions of using this code. I understand that it is a universal standard for web browsers not to be closed by client/server side scripts. But, I am, nonetheless, wondering whether this would be possible and how (preferably without installing any other applications).

Comment: Perhaps this would be possible with an additional browser plugin that would interact with your login system. Maybe there already is something out there. But why do you want to do that? I don't see the point of logging in to sth and closing the browser. And why do you force your pupil to use IE?

Comment: So is this not a login system to some browser based system but rather to a local one? Or how does it work after you closed the browser.

Comment: `window.open('', '_self').close();` does the trick even without prompting, if your page is trusted.

Comment: What did you mean by a Login system ? can you provide us more information about this or post your code to understand more your issue.perhaps HTA can be a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way IE can be closed programmatically?

Sure. Find the right IE instance in the SHELL.WINDOWS collection, then QUIT that instance. Or find the right process in Win32_Process, then TERMINATE that process. Or probably dozens of other ways.

None of which will necessarily help, unless you provide a ton more information about what you are actually doing! But that's the consequence of asking "Can I do 'X'?", instead of: "I need to achieve result 'Y', what is the best way to do that?"

You've told us 'X', but not 'Y'.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot close windows that were not opened via JavaScript.

If websites could close people's browsers, a lot of people would be angry. Your non-malicious intent is unknown to the browser.